# What technology does the Google Maps use to demonstrate the 3D building models?

Tags: python, gis, postgis, arcgis, qgis

I have been working on a project to extract the building parameters . I used Lidar technology to extract those,but few days back I was going through google maps and just saw each and every building's 3D model correctly showcased in the app,just wonder which technology google is using and how can I use this to extract the building polygon and it's parameters ,would love it ,if someone tells me about the api which I can use to extract that data ?

Comment: Check this conversation. https://www.quora.com/How-are-the-3D-models-of-buildings-generated-on-Google-Earth

Comment: Yes , I checked that out and I did some more digging and found out google is totally not in a notion to share that data,even purchase that also.